# com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID обновление от гугла

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Пришло сообщение от гугл:

"Начиная с июля в Play Console необходимо будет сообщать, используется ли в вашем приложении рекламный идентификатор. Это позволит нам предупреждать вас о том, что в вашем выпуске вместо рекламного идентификатора может появляться строка нулей. Вам будет запрещено создавать выпуски для Android 13, пока вы не заполните декларацию о рекламном идентификаторе.

Напоминаем, что для приложений, которые предназначены для Android 13 (API уровня 33) или более поздней версии и используют рекламный идентификатор, в файле AndroidManifest.xml должно быть указано обычное разрешение com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID. Это нужно, чтобы вместо рекламного идентификатора не появлялась строка нулей. Если вы не объявите разрешение в манифесте приложения или будете использовать SDK"

Вопрос: если использовался на android 10 рекламный идентификатор, потом пользователь обновился до 13 версии андроида (в теории - а в будущем это возможно будет) ему будет возвращаться 00000. И тут мы выпускаем апдейт приложения с пермишеном. Вопрос: ему после апдейта будет возвращаться такой же по значению идентификатор какой был и на 10 андроиде или он пересозаться?

Comment: Этот вопрос вам лучше в dev support адресовать. Но судя по тому тут пишут (пользователь может сбросить идентификатор), я бы не надеялся на его постоянстве вообще, не говоря об обновлениях на новые версии ОС. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en

Comment: Ответ: с большой долей вероятности такой-же как и был в 10 версии, при одном условии если пользователь, а такая возможность появилась на Андроид 12 не сбросит идентификатор вручную в настройках. Если это для вас так важно то лучше опробовать это на практике смоделировав данную ситуацию. Если устроит как ответ могу перенести.

Comment: @Style-7 приветствую, предполагать и я конечно-же могу :) Важно практически подкрепить смоделировав ситуацию. У меня такой возможности нет - а у вас ?)

Comment: Тоже нет. Важно взять на заметку тот факт, что Google также заинтересован в получении дохода через вас, но в тоже время нет гарантии, что какая-нибудь компания производитель для своих телефонов сделает все по своему.